# Understanding the prime notation for the derivative of a power function

Tags: calculus

Let's say, hypothetically, that I got this question: y = x^2

I would take the derivative by multiplying both sides by " ' ", getting y'= x'^2'

My question is whether or not the " ' " carries to the ^2 as well.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: *multiplying both sides by " ' "* is not particularly meaningful. If you mean the equivalent of $\frac{d}{dx}\left(y\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\right)$ (this is not multiplication) then yes, you take the derivative of the whole right hand side

Comment: Derivation has to do with functions.  What are the functions and it's variables ?  y(x), y(t), x(t)?

Comment: thanks for the help. I think I figured it our. You multiple both sides by d/d, and divide both sides by x, getting dy/dx=x, which is the derivative.

Comment: You *can’t* multiply by $d/dx$ because (It makes no sense).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos may like to look at this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE @quantum bontum,
I believe you have a misconception regarding the derivatives.
The notation,
$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$
If $f(x)=x^{2}$ then it's derivative is represented as,
$$f'(x)=(x^{2})'=2x$$

Here are some [videos](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL19E79A0638C8D449) of Khan academy on calculus which might help you to get some intuition regarding your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will watch the videos